# how to use EF repository's find method?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I saw some examples of using EF generic reposity. I do not have a very firm grip on LINQ so I am not able to understand how to use this method. Can you plese guide me ? Here is my code. I am not gettign how I will pass a expression to it. Will highly appriciate if you please can guide with examples.

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return objectSet.Where(filter);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in the same way you would use a linq where method.

For example if T was a User, with a Name property you could do

```
Query(u=>u.Name == "Bob");
```

this type of expression is called a lambda expression. For more details you can take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would call such a method like so, assuming you'd created a concrete repository implementation:

```
var repo = new StuffRepo();

IEnumerable<Stuff> stuff = repo.Query(s => s.SomeProperty == "Foo");
```

SO the expression, or filter, is an anonymous function (the [Func](http://www.dotnetperls.com/func)), which takes a T (in my example, a Stuff, noted by the alias "s"), and returns a boolean. So in SQL:

```
select *
from stuff s
where s.SomeProperty = "Foo"
```